# django-rest-framework How to handle multiple URL parameter?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

How can I use generic views with multiple URL parameters? Like

```
GET /author/{author_id}/book/{book_id}

class Book(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    lookup_field = 'book_id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'book_id'

    # lookup_field = 'author_id' for author
    # lookup_url_kwarg = 'author_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You'll need to use named groups in your URL structure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) and possibly [override the `get()` method of your view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#extending-generic-views).

Answer (score 4):

Just add a little [custom Mixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#customizing-the-generic-views):

in `urls.py`:

```
...

path('/author/<int:author_id>/book/<int:book_id>', views.Book.as_view()),

...
```

in `views.py`:
Adapted from example in the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#customizing-the-generic-views):

```
class MultipleFieldLookupMixin:
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()                          # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)               # Apply any filter backends
        multi_filter = {field: self.kwargs[field] for field in self.lookup_fields}
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **multi_filter)       # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj


class Book(MultipleFieldLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    lookup_fields = ['author_id', 'book_id']    # possible thanks to custom Mixin
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be late to the party here, but this is what I do:

```
class Book(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
           book_id = self.kwargs['book_id']
           author_id = self.kwargs['author_id']     
           
           return Book.objects.filter(Book = book_id, Author = author_id)
```